# Warning: Division by zero on line 485 496

Tags: php

I get this error:

> Warning: Division by zero in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\my portable
>   files\B2\seats.php on line 485
>
> Warning: Division by zero in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\my portable
>   files\B2\seats.php on line 496

php code like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if ($i % $columns == 0) {                 // line 485

  }
  if ($row['status']=='0') {    
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='service[]' id='services' value='$row[rowid]' />&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['rowid']."</td>";
  } else {  
    echo "<td>".$row['rowid'].".Sudah di pesan</td>";
  }

  if (($i % $columns) == ($columns - 1) || ($i + 1) == $num_rows) { //line 496
    echo "\n</TR>";
  }
}
```

Please help how I can fix this?

Comment: The error is telling you that `$columns` is 0. So, check the value of `$columns` before `if($i % $columns == 0)`.

Comment: From where you're getting this `$columns` value?

Comment: getting from this

$columns = $kursi / 6;
$query="SELECT * FROM kursi WHERE nobus='$nobus' and tanggal='$tanggal'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$no = 1;

echo "\n<TR>";

Answer (score 1):

In accordance to what @Brian-Ray said, your columns are 0.  The modulus operator (%) performs a division operation (To determine the "remainder" value).  If this encounters a division by 0, then this error occurs.

A common fix for this is to check for 0, and short circuit the logic in your IF statement.  This would look like:

```
 if( ($columns != 0) and ($i % $columns == 0) )
```

Since the AND (&&) logic operator is used, when the if statement encounters the first set of parenthesis (columns not equal to zero) and fails, it will not attempt to execute the if statement any further (since the outcome cannot possible be true, with an AND operator.

To fix your error on line 496 you will need to perform the same.   You can find more information about if statement short circuiting here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Thanks for ur help guys... I get that problem when I added this script [link]https://3v4l.org/3Mshu [link] if I did not add, I do not get an error..

Comment: Hello, Have you tried running the updated script with these suggested changes?

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the problem:

- Your error says "Division by zero ... on line 485".
- On line 485 is a division `$i % columns`.

This implies that `columns` is zero at this point and you're dividing by it.

To fix the problem, you need to decide:

- Should the program be allowed to reach line 485 with `columns` set to zero?

  - No: Find out why this situation was reached and stop that from happening.
  - Yes: What should the program do when it gets to this point with `columns` set to zero?

    - Make the program do that instead of what it's currently doing.